# Cannot upload to FTP server in Python

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to upload files via FTP, I have the following code:

```
def ftp_upload(localfile, remotefile):
    fp = open(localfile, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(localfile), 'rb', 1024)
    fp.close()
    print ("after upload " + localfile + " to " + remotefile)
```

The code executes with out error but does not upload any file.

Comment: Did you just forget the indentation in the post or also in the real code? If so the function returns None every time and the code below is not executed by the function.

Answer (score 1):

## Why your code does not work

You are using 'rb' as the file pointer, where you should be using the file pointer you opened

## Example code [[Source](https://pythonprogramming.net/ftp-transfers-python-ftplib/) (slightly modified)]

```
def placeFile():
    filename = 'exampleFile.txt'
    open_file = open(filename, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+filename, open_file)
    ftp.quit()
placeFile()
```